# React-Native build failed - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets' 'react-native-iap'

Tags: android, react-native

I ejected from expo and did `yarn android`. Build is failing with below error.

I did,

1. ./gradle clean
2. removed npm modules and installed again
3. re-started the computer
4. updated gradle version to latest -> 7.0.2
5. updated react-native-iap to latest -> 6.2.0

None of these fix this issue. Does anyone know why this is occurring ?

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergemyapppackageDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:myapppackageDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-iap.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'default' with value 'myapppackage'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-iap:
          - amazonDebugRuntimeElements
          - playDebugRuntimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'amazonDebugRuntimeElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'amazonDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
                  - Provides attribute 'store' with value 'amazon' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'playDebugRuntimeElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'playDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
                  - Provides attribute 'store' with value 'play' but the consumer didn't ask for it
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'amazonDebugApiElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'amazonReleaseApiElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'amazonReleaseRuntimeElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'playDebugApiElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'playReleaseApiElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'playReleaseRuntimeElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installmyapppackageDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Could not resolve project :react-native-iap: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeAlaccountingmodelmcqenudeDebugAssets'.

#### Version of react-native-iap

6.2.0

#### Version of react-native

0.63.4

#### Platforms you faced the error (IOS or Android or both?)

Android

#### Expected behavior

project should be build.

#### Actual behavior

Getting below error and build is failing.

Ran `./gradlew app:installMyapppackageDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 --stacktrace`

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergemyapppackageDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:myapppackageDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-iap.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'default' with value 'myapppackage'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-iap:
          - amazonDebugRuntimeElements
          - playDebugRuntimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'amazonDebugRuntimeElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'amazonDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
                  - Provides attribute 'store' with value 'amazon' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'playDebugRuntimeElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'playDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
                  - Provides attribute 'store' with value 'play' but the consumer didn't ask for it
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'amazonDebugApiElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'amazonReleaseApiElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'amazonReleaseRuntimeElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'playDebugApiElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'playReleaseApiElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')
          - Variant 'playReleaseRuntimeElements' capability My App:react-native-iap:unspecified declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about default (required 'myapppackage')

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergemyapppackageDebugAssets'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:71)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:155)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:171)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addEntryTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:160)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:45)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.lambda$select$0(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:128)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer$CalculateTaskGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:117)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer$CalculateTaskGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(BuildOperationFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareTaskExecution(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:233)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:167)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: add to /android/app/build.gradle


defaultConfig {
        ...
        missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play'
    }

Comment: @janbee this will make app run but unable to get its UI properly.

Comment: @Chandni for me its working fine, what do you mean by `unable to gets its UI properly` ?

Comment: button images are not showing properly

Comment: I didn't notice it, my tab icons are not showing in dev mode sometimes either, However this is the fix react-native-iap suggests at their github page i.e. https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap#breaking-changes

Comment: Solution for expo managed project:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75917340/10064816

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to make a change to the `android/app/build.gradle`:

You have two options depending on the stores you support:

a. If you only need for Google Play IAP, Insert this inside the defaultConfig section in android/app/build.gradle:

```js
defaultConfig {
      ...
      // react-native-iap: we only use the Google Play flavor
      missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play'
  }
```

b. If you are using it for both Google Play and Amazon, insert the following lines inside the android block in android/app/build.gradle

```js
android {
  ...
  flavorDimensions "appstore"
  productFlavors{
      googlePlay{
          dimension "appstore"
          missingDimensionStrategy "store", "play"
      }
      amazon{
          dimension "appstore"
          missingDimensionStrategy "store", "amazon"
      }
  }
}
```

From the library documentation: https://react-native-iap.dooboolab.com/docs/manual_install/