React Native Android Missing classes detected while running R8 error in Jenkins
I am trying to upgrade RN from 0.72 to 0.73.9
I get the below error in Jenkins (I cannot replicate the issue on local machine).
> Task :app:lintVitalAnalyzeDevRelease

timber.lint.TimberIssueRegistry in /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/26daadcd46ecfc898dac002daac9b73b/transformed/jetified-timber-4.7.1/jars/lint.jar does not specify a vendor; see IssueRegistry#vendor



> Task :app:lintVitalReportDevRelease

> Task :app:lintVitalDevRelease



> Task :app:minifyDevReleaseWithR8 FAILED

ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in /home/jenkins/workspace/APP_PR-1867/android/app/build/outputs/mapping/devRelease/missing_rules.txt.

ERROR: R8: Missing class edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings (referenced from: void com.jwplayer.c.a.f.onMetadata(androidx.media3.common.Metadata))

Missing class kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize (referenced from: io.didomi.sdk.Purpose and 10 other contexts)

ASM Instrumentation process wasn't able to resolve some classes, this means that

the instrumented classes might contain corrupt stack frames. Make sure the

dependencies that contain these classes are on the runtime or the provided

classpath. Otherwise, the jvm might fail to load the corrupt classes at runtime

when running in a jvm environment like unit tests.



Classes that weren't resolved:

> com.jwplayer.pub.api.configuration.PlayerConfig

> com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastSession

> com.jwplayer.pub.api.JWPlayer$PlayerInitializationListener

> com.jwplayer.api.b.a.l

> com.jwplayer.api.b.a.a

> com.jwplayer.c.m

> com.jwplayer.api.b.a.k

> com.jwplayer.a.a

> com.jwplayer.a.h

> com.jwplayer.c.e

-- 74 more classes --





FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:minifyDevReleaseWithR8'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable

   > Compilation failed to complete

I've tried editing the proguard-rules.pro file and adding:
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep @interface edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.**
-keep class kotlinx.parcelize.** { *; }
-keep @kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize class * {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
-keep class com.jwplayer.pub.api.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.** { *; }
-keep class com.jwplayer.** { *; }

but this doesn't seem to affect in any way the above errors.
I am using https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-react-native
content of app/build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    dev: ".env.dev",
    staging: ".env.staging",
    prod: ".env.prod",
]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"




react {
    entryFile = file("../../index.js")
}


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

class BuildConfig {
    static final int versionMajor = 10
    static final int versionMinor = 6
    static final int versionFix = 2
    static final int playstoreVersionSuffix = 0
}

ext {
    buildConfig = new BuildConfig()
    RNJWPlayerUseGoogleCast = true
    exoplayerVersion = '2.18.1'
    JWPlayerVersion = '4.18.2'
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "<myNameSpaceisHere>"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<myAppIdHere>"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        // versionCode BuildConfig.versionMajor * 1000000 + 3 * 10000 + BuildConfig.versionFix * 100 + BuildConfig.playstoreVersionSuffix
        versionCode BuildConfig.versionMajor * 1000000 + BuildConfig.versionMinor * 10000 + BuildConfig.versionFix * 100 + BuildConfig.playstoreVersionSuffix
        versionName "${BuildConfig.versionMajor}.${BuildConfig.versionMinor}.${BuildConfig.versionFix}"
        multiDexEnabled true

        // react-native-iap: we only use the Google Play flavor, this needs an update if we use amazon too!!
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941766/react-native-build-failed-could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-appm
        missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play'

        // https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#android-setup
        manifestPlaceholders = [
          appAuthRedirectScheme: "<myNameSpaceisHere>"
        ]

        // https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#advanced-android-setup
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "<myNameSpaceisHere>"

        // https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/android-sdk#specifying-where-to-find-the-buildconfig-class
        resValue "string", "wonderpush_buildConfigPackage", "<myNameSpaceisHere>"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../keystore/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

        release {
            storeFile file(System.getenv("APP_KEYSTORE") ?: '../keystore/debug.keystore')
            storePassword System.getenv("APP") ?: 'android'
            keyAlias System.getenv("APP") ?: 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword System.getenv("APP") ?: 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
           
            signingConfig isIdeBuild() ? signingConfigs.debug : signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            debuggable isIdeBuild()
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "server"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "server"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix hyphen(buildVersionNameSuffix('dev'))
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_INFO", quoted(buildVersionNameSuffix("dev"))
        }
        staging {
            dimension "server"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            versionNameSuffix hyphen(buildVersionNameSuffix('staging'))
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_INFO", quoted(buildVersionNameSuffix("staging"))
        }
        prod {
            dimension "server"
            String branchName = System.getenv('BRANCH_NAME') ?: ""

            if (isIdeBuild()) {
                versionNameSuffix hyphen(buildVersionNameSuffix("prod"))
                buildConfigField "String", "APP_INFO", quoted(buildVersionNameSuffix("prod"))
            } else {
                if (!branchName.startsWith("release/")) {
                    versionNameSuffix hyphen(buildVersionNameSuffix("prod"))
                    buildConfigField "String", "APP_INFO", quoted(buildVersionNameSuffix("prod"))
                } else {
                    buildConfigField "String", "APP_INFO", quoted("")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def apkName = "app-${variant.name}-${android.defaultConfig.versionName}-${variant.buildType.name}"

        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }
        }

        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = "${apkName}.apk"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
        checkAllWarnings true
        warningsAsErrors true
    }
}

def gitSha() {
    if (isIdeBuild()) {
        return "devbuild"
    } else {
        if (System.getenv("GIT_COMMIT") != null) {
            return System.getenv("GIT_COMMIT").substring(0, 7)
        } else {
            return "devbuild"
        }
    }
}

def buildVersionNameSuffix(String environment) {
    def upperCaseEnv = environment.toUpperCase()
    if (upperCaseEnv == "PROD") {
        return ""
    }
    return "${System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER')}-${environment}-${gitSha()}"
}

private static quoted(string) {
    return "\"$string\""
}

private static hyphen(String string) {
    if (!string.isEmpty()) {
        return "-$string"
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1"

    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation 'com.dailymotion.dailymotion-sdk-android:sdk:0.2.10'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'


    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion"

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:${safeExtGet('castFrameworkVersion', '+')}"
    implementation 'io.didomi.sdk:android:1.86.3'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"

    // JWPlayer SDK
    implementation "com.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:$JWPlayerVersion"
    implementation "com.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:$JWPlayerVersion"
    implementation "com.jwplayer:jwplayer-chromecast:$JWPlayerVersion"
    implementation "com.jwplayer:jwplayer-ima:$JWPlayerVersion"
}


def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
  rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)


content of build.gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 28
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"
        androidXAnnotation = "1.2.0"
        androidXBrowser = "1.3.0"
        castFrameworkVersion = "21.3.0"

        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion='1.9.10'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version "0.38.0"
}

allprojects {
    tasks.withType(Javadoc).all { enabled = false }

    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            // JW Player
            url 'https://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"


dependencyUpdates.resolutionStrategy = {
    componentSelection { rules ->
        rules.all { ComponentSelection selection ->
            boolean rejected = ['alpha', 'beta'].any { qualifier ->
                selection.candidate.version ==~ /(?i).*[.-]${qualifier}[.\d-]*/
            }
            if (rejected) {
                selection.reject('Release candidate')
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

def isIdeBuild() {
    return properties.containsKey("android.injected.invoked.from.ide")
}


Fixed with adding:
-dontwarn com.jwplayer.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.**
-dontwarn kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

in android/app/proguard-rules.pro
Inspired from: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/1700#issuecomment-2298021503
Important: Take a close attention to the logs, the above error could be just a warning for you and there might be a compilation error there hidden between warnings. I noticed locally with zulu 17 jdk such error didn't show up but Jenkins was using another distribution of jdk 17.
